# Laravel raw JSON response

Tags: json, laravel

I am trying to get Laravel to return raw json to the browser but it seems to be encapsulating it into a wrapper. called JsonResponse. This is so I can consume it via Ajax.

I am calling the code from a controller like the below:

```
        return response()->json(['name' => 'Virat Gandhi', 'state' => 'Gujarat']);
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

[image]

What I am really wanting to return is: `{'name' : 'Virat Gandhi', 'state' :'Gujarat']`

Comment: That looks like you `dd()`ed out the response instead of returning it. Your code as shown in the question is fine.

Comment: Have you tried accessing your code in Javascript, like: response.data.name // Virat. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather stupidly, I was outputting a dd() in a later function.